# popviewcontroller not loading with updated data

Tags: ios, ipad, ios6

i am new to iOS and using ios6. I need to save to save data by clicking save button on the page and display the updated in the previous page.
I used

**`[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];`**

but with this the page is loading with old details not with updated one
and if i use the below

```
**[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];**
```

nothing is coming

any one please help me

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure that after you click save button, your data in database has been updated
2. In the view that displaying data, try place all your web service (reload table, get json data from server) inside`viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated`

Comment: After click the save button the database is getting updated properly, because when open the next time it is showing the updated data.I also added code to reload date in viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated but still nothing is showing.